# Application Loader cannot choose zip file of my Mac app

Tags: cocoa, macos, app-store, app-store-connect

The status of my Mac app is "Waiting for upload". When I launch Application Loader, I can select it from the list. However when I click on "Choose...", I cannot select the zip file of my app (or any other file of any kind). I tried uploading an iPhone app to see if Application Loader has a problem and it works just fine. Am I missing something here? or has Apple changed anything lately with the launch of XCode 4?. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give Application Loader a PKG for Mac apps or an IPA for iPhone apps. You cannot upload a ZIP file. You can generate these files in Xcode 4 by doing Product > Archive and then exporting from the Archives panel of the Organizer.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Xcode 4 and used its new way of uploading binary files to iTunes Connect and it worked. But I really wonder why Application Loader didn't manage to upload the file.