# application loader submiting with metadata

Tags: iphone, macos, loader

I have my app running correctly. 
I have run the Package maker to produce a pkg

Nevertheless, if I try to upload with the Application Loader it always returns me :

> - The archive is invalid. Unexpected productutil output: the product Meta-data must be present
> - Product archive "/Users/....path to my app/Myapp.pkg is a directory"

This should be a little thing but I spent hours and didn't find out.

Comment: Whereas you too are telling me using a zip with Application Loader, I still can't select mine but only a "pkg" file. Is this about the 1.4.1 version I have ?

Comment: A first Answer was found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362388/application-loader-cannot-choose-zip-file-of-my-mac-app now : how to do this without app loader ?

Comment: Well I recreate a certificate imported it in the keychain mger, evaluated it with success. Now I'm rejected during the build : "Code signing identity '----' does not match any valid, non-expired, code-signing certificate in your keychain"

Answer (score 0):

Application loader expects a ZIP file. The ZIP it expects is made from the .app folder - Compress that and upload the resulting .zip file.

Comment: application loader expects a pkg in fact, I can't choose anything else. In addition, with the new Xcode my app is in "../Xcode/derivedData/Myappqozlqihdussddf/build/products/release" dir now the app dir doesn't include the executable

Answer (score 0):

Compress your project.app file,so a .zip file will be created.You can use this .zip file in your Application Loader.

Remember to make a distribution binary with your distribution certificate if you are planning to upload this file on itunes connect.

Cheers

Comment: please : what do you mean by >make a distribution binary with your distribution certificate

Comment: Distribution binary means the build file of your project which you want to submit for Apple's approval.You need to build this with the distribution certificate,not the developer certificate...

Comment: Does this implies "build for archive" with the distribution certificate ?.

Comment: NO simply build your code as you do for development BUT with the distribution profile...

Comment: well there are 'build for running' Testing archiving. I'm sorry I don't get the "distribution profile": I already include the .cer in the Build settings / Code signing / code signing identity

Answer (score 0):

it's weird: the Browse dialog for Application loader only accepts .pbk files. Drag&CDrop via the dock only accepts .zip files - and dropping a zip file too gives me the described error messages. choosing the .PKG via the browse dialog works on. strage, but hopefully this helps?